# Is it possible to have template class methods using AliasSeq in d/dlang?

Tags: templates, d, static-analysis

I would like to compile something like the following:

```
import std.meta: AliasSeq;
import std.stdio: writeln;

class Bag {
    template fill(alias types) {
        void fill() {
            writeln("Do stuff");
        }
    }
}

void main(){
    auto bag = new Bag();
    alias stuff = AliasSeq!(int, ubyte[]);
    bag.fill!(stuff)();
}
```

But I cannot get this to compile.  Is there a bug in the code I am not seeing, or is there something more fundamentally wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just used the wrong kind of argument to the template. Try `template fill(types...)` instead of `template fill(alias types)` and it should compile.

An `AliasSeq` is a sequence of template arguments and corresponds to a variadic `...` thing instead of a single symbol, which is what an `alias` thing does.